# pass php generated array to another php file via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have generated a php array from oracle db (index.php)

```
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array ($stid, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)){

    $result[]=$row;

}
```

Now i have to pass this array to another php file for other processing.

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  function sortme()
   {  
    var d=document.getElementById("div");
    var obj = <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        d.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
     }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getsorted.php?q=obj",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
   }
```

Then in the php file get sorted.php i need this double dimension array "result" back and sort it. So I use this, (getsorted.php)

```
   <?php

    $q=$_GET["q"];
    $ans=json_decode(str_replace('\"','"',$q),true);
    var_dump($q);
    var_dump($ans);
   ?>
```

But i am not able to figure out anything.I am not able to retrieve the array back.
If this is the wrong approach please suggest a correct approach.

Please do post the code.

Thanks a lot.

IS there a better way to do it???

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the string "obj" when you have to pass the URLEncoded JSON representation. Replace:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getsorted.php?q=obj",true);
```

with:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getsorted.php?q=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj)),true);
```

---

What you are doing is somewhat like this:

```
PHP file  AnotherPHPFile
   |           ^  |
   |       ____|  |
   V      /       v
Javascript---(sorted result into HTML)
```

How about simply including the `getsorted.php` file in your `index.php` and straightaway use the sorting functionality. You save a network request that way..

Comment: Thanks,
2 Questions.
Firstly this does not work :(.
Secondly, how shall i include this getsorted in the same file.I am calling the javascript function on click of a table header to sort the table with respect to that header.So without javascript how do I do it?

Comment: Ignore the second part of the answer if you are going to fire the AJAX request upon the click of a button. First part still holds. What is the exact problem? Do you see the request going (and the corresponding response) in the browser's inspector?